# Project can't find framework when creating release build

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, frameworks, linker

I've added a new framework to my project.
I dragged the .xcodeproj file of the framework as a child of my project.
I added the product of that project into the main project's Target Dependencies, Link Binary with Libraries and Copy Files (frameworks).
I have no problems building a test release or executing my project.

But if I try to create an archive release or if I try to profile the project it fails with the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Something", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DasProject-F7DB55F503641F0A.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

**tl;dr:** I can create and execute a debug build without problems, archive builds can't find a specific framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new Cocoa Framework from scratch and copied over the .h and .m files I needed. This fixed the problem.

After comparing the build options between this framework and others I'm using and not seeing anything out of place I really suspect this is a bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your "Library Search Path" ("Build Settings" -> "Search Paths") to "$(TARGET_BUILD_DIR)" or "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)" (in my projects they are the same)
Also check appropriate checkboxes in the target's build scheme as noted in [Tools Workflow Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/AA-Developing_a_Static_Library_and_Incorporating_It_in_Your_Application/archiving_an_application_that_uses_a_static_library.html) (Ignore that it is iOS doc, just look at the image)

Comment: I am linking to other frameworks without any problems. Why would I need to change my main project because of this particular framework?

Comment: Doesn't work. Cleaned the project, tried to profile and fails with the same error.

Comment: ok, now check "Architectures" build settings in your framework project. It must be the same for both Debug and Release configuration. Also check "Build Active Architecture Only" setting. It must be the same as in your main project.

Comment: Everything matches but after removing and re-adding the framework both release and debug builds fail now. For the record, I was able to use the code in the framework previously. I suspect a bug in Xcode.

Comment: May be some name conflicts with other framework (for example system's) and it links with wrong library?

Comment: I'm using this: https://github.com/joeroback/SSHTunnel I don't think it would clash with anything.